# SQL simple nested select query is getting blocked

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, sqltransaction

In the system I'm using the below query in order to get a portion of my table's data in order to implement pagination. The table contains around 100 records only right now but it will grow into 1 million+ records later on.

```
 SELECT 
    Id AS ActualMapping_Id,
    BudgetPhase  AS ActualMapping_BudgetPhase,
    FromBH AS ActualMapping_FromBH,
    ToBH AS ActualMapping_ToBH,
    FromBI AS ActualMapping_FromBI,
    ToBI AS ActualMapping_ToBI,
    FromSI1 AS ActualMapping_FromSI1,
    ToSI1 AS ActualMapping_ToSI2,
    FromSI2 AS ActualMapping_FromSI2,
    ToSI2 AS ActualMapping_ToSI2,
    DataType AS ActualMapping_DataType,
    Status AS ActualMapping_Status,
    MappingType AS ActualMapping_MappingType,
    LastMappedBy AS ActualMapping_LastMappedBy,
    LastMappedDate AS ActualMapping_LastMappedDate
  FROM
 (
 SELECT
    Id,
    BudgetPhase,
    FromBH,
    ToBH,
    FromBI,
    ToBI,
    FromSI1,
    ToSI1,
    FromSI2,
    ToSI2,
    DataType,
    Status,
    MappingType,
    LastMappedBy,
    LastMappedDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FromBH) AS RowNumber
FROM
    ActualMapping
WHERE
    DataType = 'Cost' and 
    Status = 'Active' and
    MappingType = 'Static' and 
    BudgetPhase like '%some_text%' and
    ToBH like '%some_text%' and
    ToBI like '%some_text%' and 
    ToSI1 like '%some_text%' and 
    ToSI2 like '%some_text%' and
    FromBH like '%some_text%' and 
    FROMBI like '%some_text%' and
    FROMSI1 like '%some_text%' and
    FROMSI2 like '%$some_text%'
) AS NumberedTable
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

The above query which works pretty fine (At least on ~100 records) but after a while it starts getting blocked. I can't understand the possible reason for it getting blocked but when that happens I won't be able to do a simple select query from the table unless I kill all those blocked queries which are piled up.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the query gets blocked after a while?
2. Is this a good/ok approach to implement pagination on sql side for a large data set? (possibly more than 1 million+ records)

Comment: double `%%` queries require a table scan - you may want to consider full text indexes

Comment: what is the index status of the table? When you run the query, are there any insert, update, delete actions on the table?

Comment: @cqi There are no other queries running at the same time. just the nested select